# Changing the default voice of Android's Text To Speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm using the Android's **Text To Speech** default engine in my app, however the female's voice sounds like a woman over 40 and her voice is somewhat robotic.

I saw other apps that seems to use Google's built in TTS, but it sounds a lot better i.e young woman with a more natural voice.

That "natural" voice is also being used in the Android main **Google Search** e.g. when you press on the mic and ask a question (Siri style) like "who is the president of the US", the woman's voice will tell you the answer.

How can this voice be achieved in the code?

Basically this is what I do in my code:

```
    TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
          .
          .
          .
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Comment: You can try and change the pitch to see if something works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've eventually managed to find a solution. I just needed to use the KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS param which is available on jellybean. The default offline mode has the awful robotic sound

Comment: Can you please show how exactly can i pass "KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS" as a parameter?

Comment: Can you please explain how to use it

Answer (score 4):

Here is my code to use `KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS` param:

```
HashMap<String, String> onlineSpeech = new HashMap<>();
onlineSpeech.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_FEATURE_NETWORK_SYNTHESIS, "true");
tts.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, onlineSpeech);
```

Comment: Its'd deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change this within the `TextToSpeech`.  You can download other applications that replace it however, with the current system you can only set the language and set the pitch. If you are just wanting something different you can get a British accent by setting it to English UK.  Ivona  is one of the biggest alternatives to googles text to speech voice.

Comment: Thanks, but how come that the voice that is being used in the Android Google Search is different (at least sounds different in my Samsung device)?
Also I saw some apps that use the same natural voice as Google's and didn't seem to download any external voice DB (they were pretty light).

Comment: @GarnerK can you provide an app for reference for me to look?  I can tell you what they are doing if you can give a reference app.