# Changing default voice in android TTS

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I wanted to play some text in android using default tts engine
but currently in default TTs engine will support only female voice

is there any option in default TTs library to change current female voice to some cute
cartoon voice.?

or is there any other external library to change voice to some cute voice.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914297/changing-the-default-voice-of-androids-text-to-speech This seems to be similar problem as of yours.

Comment: ya i got your link Gaurav, just wanted to know is there any external libs available and how talking tom like apps speaking in different voice

Comment: Yes you can get third party tts engine installed on your phone and mark them as default engine for tts. Note: These engines are heavy( in size )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115458/is-it-possible-to-embed-tts-in-android This link explain the same in better way.

Comment: I believe Talking Tom records the voice then shifts its frequency and plays it back, I don't think it's doing TTS at all.